# How to display a calendar based on selected month and year from a form input using FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a form where users can select a year and month using custom date pickers. Upon submission of the form, I want to display a calendar for the selected month and year using FullCalendar. However, I'm unsure about how to pass the selected year and month values from the form to FullCalendar to dynamically generate the calendar.

Here's my form structure:

```
<form class="navbar-search" action="search.php?id=<?= $id ?>" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="year">YEAR:</label>
            <input name="year" value="<?=$year?>" class="form-control form-control-user" id="yearpicker" placeholder="Please Choose..." autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="month">MONTH :</label>
            <input name="month" value="<?=$month?>" class="form-control form-control-user" id="monthpicker" placeholder="Please Choose..." autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <button name="search" id="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"><i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i> SEARCH</button>
    <hr>
</form>
```

I'm using **customise datepicker** in this form input btw.

[image: Search Field]

And here's the calendar:

[image: FullCalendar]

And here's the JavaScript I'm using with FullCalendar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: "fetch-event.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>",
            displayEventTime: false,
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                    event.allDay = false;
                }
            },
        });
```

Could someone please guide me on how to pass the selected year and month values from the form to FullCalendar so that it can display the calendar accordingly?

Thank you.

Comment: First question: why are you using such an old version of fullCalendar? The newest versions have much better performance, more features and less bugs, and don't require jQuery. Check it out on the fullCalendar website

Comment: But if you insist on that version, you can call the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/gotoDate function anytime you want to change the calendar's date. To set the date when the calendar is loaded the first time, use the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/defaultDate option. (Equivalent options and functions exist in the newer version too but are named differently and may operate slightly differently - check the documentation.)

Comment: I'm sorry but can you elaborate how to use gotoDate function? i still dont get it. thanks!

Comment: It's just a function you can call. e.g. `$("#calendar").fullCalendar( "gotoDate", "2022-01-01" );`. See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/methods for general help on using the functions in fullcalendar 3. And see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc for general help on using fullcalendar 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it now thanks to [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) ! I figure it out.

I added the `date` variable to store date from php. And `gotoDate`  method in fullCalendar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // editable: true,
            events: "fetch-event.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>",
            displayEventTime: false,
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                    event.allDay = false;
                }
            },
        });
        date = '<?= $tahun ?>-<?= date('m', strtotime($bulan)) ?>-01';
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
    });
```

See also [fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/methods](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/methods) for general help on using the functions in fullcalendar 3. And see [fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc) for general help on using fullcalendar 3.